# Sharepoint workflow not seen in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created a VS 2013 app for Sharepoint. I have created work flow as well. I am deploying this solution to online sharepoint ( 365). I see my app published but i do not see my work flow.

Any suggestion this is maddening me.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue. Actually the workflow did get published. It was published in the App and i was searching in the main sharepoint site.